# MouseEnter event is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two speech bubbles changing their content every two seconds.
I am trying that each time i put my mouse over the bubbles my changeComment functions stops, this way the user will have more time to read the comment, and when the mouse leaves the bubbles the function will start again.

I have my demo here: http://jsbin.com/EMogAfud/1

This are the functions I am using

```
$("bubbleSpeech").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(intervalStop);
});

$("bubbleSpeech").mouseleave(function(){
  show();
  intervalStop=setInterval(show,pause);
});
```

Not quite sure why it's not working. I am not getting the event fire.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure you want to use `$('#bubbleSpeech')`

Comment: Did you just forget a `#` in front of the selector? `$("#bubbleSpeech")`. Also please post relevant html as well in your question.

Comment: very very pretty sure you want to do this

Comment: May I ask why you're using jQuery for this? the code isn't any more complex without it, but jQUery is, in major browsers, up to 95% slower than `getElementById()` ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. I have understood that there is no mouseenter event. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp  If I am wrong, correct me please

Comment: There is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events#Standard_events

That's why you don't use w3schools ;) Oh, and if there was none, how should jQuery be able to bind it? ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. hi I have a new demo here, but it doesn't work. http://jsbin.com/EMogAfud/3 If I use the jquery is working.

Comment: In DOM, it's element.onmouseenter and element.onmouseleave - with the on prefixed. Change it  it'll work, i tried ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. Yes it does. I was going to right you that in your answer. http://jsbin.com/ejiFixeG/1. I will not trust w3school then

Comment: Yes, my answer wasn't that thought-through (to avoid the term bullshit ^^), so I deleted it again. My bad, I didn't notice the missing on right away ;)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use the '#' :

```
$("#bubbleSpeech").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(intervalStop);
});

$("#bubbleSpeech").mouseleave(function(){
  show();
  intervalStop=setInterval(show,pause);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `#`

[id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$("#bubbleSpeech")
^ // added # for id-selector
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments
They are two ways for doing this.

**Using Jquery**

```
$("#bubbleSpeech").mouseenter(function(){
  clearInterval(intervalStop);
});

$("#bubbleSpeech").mouseleave(function(){
  show();
  intervalStop=setInterval(show,pause);
});
```

**Or using pure javascript**

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ejiFixeG/2

```
mainSlider=document.getElementById('bubbleSpeech');

mainSlider.onmouseenter = function(){
  clearTimeout(timerStop)   ;
  clearInterval(intervalStop);
};

mainSlider.onmouseleave = function(){
  show();
  intervalStop=setInterval(show,pause);
};
```